How can I improve the paving of blocks in a mermaid block diagram?
I group objects first by blocks, and then by areas.
Do you want to make a beautiful block diagram? with normal paving of blocks (absence of empty space, adequate block sizes) in mermaid, however, it is unclear how to bring it to an adequate appearance, for example, as in В3 nested treemaps.
Here is an example of a training project, there is not much data, but not much with the location of the blocks.The more data there is, the worse it gets.
block-beta
  block: DRY_Cleaning
   columns 4
      block:Customer_Service_Dept.
        columns 1
                CP
                CLS
                PP
                end
    block:Customes.
        columns 1
                CC
                TTY
                end
    block:Department_of_Finance
        columns 1
                FINANCE
                end
    block:Department_of_Marketing 
        columns 1
                MRKT
                end
    block:Production_Department
        columns 1
                 PPC
                 CLE
                 IRON
                 WSH
                end
    block: Technical_Department
        columns 1
                EQ
                end
    block:Economic_Department
        columns 1
                MII
                end
    block:Accounting_Department
        columns 1
                ACC
                end
    block:Department_of_Logistics
        columns 1
                LOG
                end
                end
    


I want to get something like in d3 nested treemaps.

What could be done to improve my chart?
